Sparklines sourcedata
If sourcedata for sparklines is a string, how can you advance the string by six rows repetitively to fill multiple sparkline graphs
Sourcedata =“d5:s5”

To correct syntax for
Sourcedata = “d5+6:s5+6”

To go down six rows and repeat multiple times
Sub High()
'
' High Macro
' Graph high temps
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+H
'
    Dim counter As Integer
    Dim incre As Integer
    
    incre = 0
    
    For counter = 1 To 50
    
    Range(Cells(5 + incre, 23), Cells(10 + incre, 29)).Select
    Selection.Merge
    Range(Cells(5 + incre, 23)).SparklineGroups.Add Type:=xlSparkLine, SourceData:="d6:s6"
    Selection.SparklineGroups.Item(1).SeriesColor.Color = 9592887
    Selection.SparklineGroups.Item(1).SeriesColor.TintAndShade = 0
    Selection.SparklineGroups.Item(1).Points.Negative.Color.Color = 208
    Selection.SparklineGroups.Item(1).Points.Negative.Color.TintAndShade = 0
    Selection.SparklineGroups.Item(1).Points.Markers.Color.Color = 208
    Selection.SparklineGroups.Item(1).Points.Markers.Color.TintAndShade = 0
    Selection.SparklineGroups.Item(1).Points.Highpoint.Color.Color = 208
    Selection.SparklineGroups.Item(1).Points.Highpoint.Color.TintAndShade = 0
    Selection.SparklineGroups.Item(1).Points.Lowpoint.Color.Color = 208
    Selection.SparklineGroups.Item(1).Points.Lowpoint.Color.TintAndShade = 0
    Selection.SparklineGroups.Item(1).Points.Firstpoint.Color.Color = 208
    Selection.SparklineGroups.Item(1).Points.Firstpoint.Color.TintAndShade = 0
    Selection.SparklineGroups.Item(1).Points.Lastpoint.Color.Color = 208
    Selection.SparklineGroups.Item(1).Points.Lastpoint.Color.TintAndShade = 0
    
    incre = incre + 6
    
    Next counter
    
End Sub



please share an example. You can also make an anonymous sample sheet.

share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output
